# upload directories from local computer to ec2 server

Tags: amazon-ec2

I was wondering how to set up filezilla or how to upload files to my ec2 server. everytime i try to set up filezilla it says:

```
 Error: Disconnected: No supported authentication methods available (server sent: publickey)
Error:  Could not connect to server
```

and i have to go to downloads folder and login with ssh -i **key.pem** user@ipaddress every time i want to have access since my mac wont automatically ssh from anywhere since i cant import it into my keychain.

Comment: Well, I think more info is needed on your EC2 server. I assume linux? Which distribution/EC2 image?

Comment: @JoachimIsaksson ubuntu 64 bit ec2 AWS

Comment: There's a guide [here](http://www.edukatr.com/how-to-start-an-ec2-ubuntu-server-for-your-developer-in-6-minutes/) how to set up SSH access using password authentication to the box in case you can't import your keys to the keychain. I recommend you filter SSH access to your subnet though instead of opening to any host.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use sshfs to fuse the ec2 instance directory to your local folder. 
So, you have to do following steps :

1. install sshfs on your mac.
2. put you mac id_rsa.pub key inside authorized keys in .ssh/ folder of ec2 instance . this will allow you to mount ec2 directory to local folder. Also, this will allow you to ssh to ec2 instance without using key.pem.
3. mount the ec2 instance using following command :

`sshfs ubuntu@ec2-xx-xx-xx-xxx.compute-1.amazonaws.com: /<your new folder location>`

4. don't forget to give your folders write permissions , so that you can edit them remotely.

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 2):

According to the [FileZilla Docs](http://wiki.filezilla-project.org/Howto#SFTP_using_SSH2%3a_Key_based_authentication), it should be possible:

> FileZilla supports the standard SSH agents. If your SSH agent is running, the SSH_AUTH_SOCK environment variable should be set.

[Here is a documentation](http://mah.everybody.org/docs/ssh) on how to set up ssh agent.

However I personally use [Cyberduck](http://cyberduck.ch/) as an SFTP client. When creating a new connection there, you can simply check "Use public key authorization" and give the path to your key file. Should be easier to set up.

Comment: +1 for Cyberduck. It is new to me and looks promising. I will try it out now.